# Issues with Foreign Key Constraint MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert data from a text file into a table that has a foreign key with another table which I already loaded up with data. For some reason though I can't seem to insert anything into this new table.

Here's my code that I used to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE GENRE
(
genre_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (genre_name)
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
isbn int NOT NULL,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL,
genre_nm varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (isbn),
CONSTRAINT fk_BOOK FOREIGN KEY (genre_nm)
REFERENCES GENRE(genre_name)
);
```

Then my INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO BOOK 
->   (isbn,title,genre_nm,price) 
->  VALUES 
->   (582394706,'I Shall Be Near to You: A Novel','drama',25.31),
->   (199978896,'A Breath of Frost ','fiction',41.99),
->   (506705707,'The Death Class: A True Story About Life','psychology',25.99),
->   (582553303,'The Walking Dead','comics',18.67),
->   (780701543,'Anna Karenina','drama',29.99),
->   (213261709,'A bad day','drama',14.98),
->   (457697612,'Believe in yourself','psychology',97.12),
->   (99897086,'A place behind the pines','fiction',24.23),
->   (729326086,'Near empty','comics',9.99);
```

And the error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`homework`.`book`, CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_nm`) REFERENCES `GENRE`
(`genre_name`))
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM GENRE; 
+-------------+ 
| genre_name  |
+-------------+ 
| comics      | 
| drama       | 
| fiction     |
| psychology  |
+-------------+ 
4 rows in set (0.00 sec –
```

Comment: That means that your foreign keys works as expected: you are not allowed to insert books with genres that don't exist.

Comment: Make sure that you have all genres in the GENRE table that you are trying to insert into BOOKS.

Comment: remove the relationships between the two tables, add the data then create the relationships again

Comment: What is in your GENRE table?

Comment: mysql> SELECT * FROM GENRE;
+--------------------------------------------+
| genre_name                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
| comics                                     |
| drama                                      |
| fiction                                    |
psychology |
+--------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec